# Are Chrome based browsers independent from google?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I was wondering if these secure browsers like Brave, Ghost have no backdoor of some sort from Google. And Google still doesn't collect the data through them.

Comment: Chromium and Chrome are two different projects.  Google is a major contributor to the Chromium project.

Answer (score 3):

Brave, Ghost, and many other browser are based on Chromium, which is Google's open source browser.  The browsers themselves are free of Google Chrome's data collection.

Does that prevent Google, or anyone else, from collecting data on you?  No.  However, that is a different question.